# How does my pre-cooked Costco chicken breast not expire for another 5 weeks?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I bought some "fully cooked chicken breast strips" that are seasoned and has grill lines on them. They're quite tasty. Ingredients also include salt, potato starch, and vinegar.

The label says "best before" a date that is 5 weeks from now. I don't think there is enough salt or vinegar to preserve these since the chicken tastes like normal chicken and these aren't "cured" or pickled or the like. My understanding is cooked chicken usually goes bad after about 5-7 days.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are chicken, salt, potato starch and vinegar the *only* ingredients?

Comment: Are they packed in a sealed package? Could you add a photo?

Comment: No photo sorry. They come in a plastic package that is sealed yes, but not vacuum sealed. Yes, those are the only ingredients!

Comment: Maybe you are reading the expiry date wrong (for example day and month reversed - various countries write them one way or the opposite way)? Another thought is that there are unlisted ingredients for preservation (probably ones you would rather not find in food), there are supposedly some laws that if ingredients are less then a certain amount or percentage, they don't have to be listed.

Comment: @yannn the date is SEPTEMBER 4 or similar, there's no ambiguity about the date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep in mind that the best before date is only valid until the package is opened.  Once it is opened, you must treat the chicken strips as if they were fresh and consume them within a few days.
Most likely the chicken is using 'modified atmosphere packaging' (MAP).  It's a very common method used to extend shelf life of meats and vegetables but since it doesn't look a whole lot different than regular packaging, many consumers aren't aware of it.  Wikipedia has explained the process fairly well.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_atmosphere